# TFS 2010 install - where to enter SQL Server credentials

Tags: tfs

I am installing TFS 2010 on a server, on which I am an admin. The database is on a different server that I am not an admin on, but the DBA gave me a temp login with the permissions needed to install and configure TFS. So I have two different logins, one for the tfs server, and one for the SQL Server.

During the TFS install I can enter the server name but when I click "List available databases" it errors out. Do I need to ask the DBA to give my TFS admin server login the permissions on SQL Server? Or do I just need a little more permissions in SQL Server so I can list the databases, then when I enter the SQL Server login to connect?

Comment: Why are you installing a 5 year old version of TFS?

Comment: Mainstream suport for TFS 2010 ends in July 2015!

Comment: I know, always the same "why do you" instead of an answer, but I have to mentioning the huge enhancements that come with TFS 2013 or even TFS 2015 (to come in some month). Be aware that you can normally only skip one version for an in place upgrade. You will have a lots of work before you when you install an old version and step-by-step upgrade :)

Comment: Setting up a test.  We are currently on 2010 and i am testing the upgrade to 2012. Can't go higher because we are on 2008r2 sql server and can't afford upgrade yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS needs pregnant access to SQL server as SYS Admin.

The instance of SQL used by TFS is part of the TFS application and should not be used for anything else. This is why SQL server standard comes included with TFS for a single server config.

The TFS install account needs SYS Admin, as does the account that TFS runs under. In addition any attempt to modify the configuration of SQL from that setup and used by TFS will result in an unsupportable instance.